# Group action with maximal rank

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups, group-actions

I am working on matrix Lie group actions and I want to figure out what we mean by maximal rank group acting on a manifold. Reading from "Representation Theory of Finite Groups" and "Finite group theory", I've understood that the rank of a group $G$ acting transitively on a set/manifold $M$ is the number of orbits of the double action
$$ \sigma^2 : G \times (M\times M)\rightarrow M\times M,$$ $$\;\sigma^2(g,(m_1,m_2)):=(gm_1,gm_2). $$

On this paper https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-035-02/S0002-9939-1972-0310808-1/S0002-9939-1972-0310808-1.pdf the authors talk about **maximal rank** action, do they mean that the group acts transitively on the whole product space $M\times M$?

My second "guess", looking at the proof in this paper, is that it is of maximal rank just if the differential of the map
$$ \theta_m : G\rightarrow M $$
is surjective for any $m\in M$, i.e. $\theta_m$ is always a submersion. Is this the right definition?

Comment: Your link doesn't go anywhere. Either $G$ is fixed, and of all manifolds it could act on $M$ maximizes the rank, or $M$ is fixed and of all matrix Lie group actions on it $G$'s action maximizes the rank (in neither case do we assume uniqueness). Notice $G$ cannot act transitively on $M\times M$ because the diagonal copy of $M$ is already an orbit and a proper subset. The other points of $M\times M$ forming a single other orbit is equivalent to $G$ having a $2$-transitive action on $M$ (note $2$-transitive actions of finite groups and Lie groups are classified).

Comment: Now I've replaced the link and it should work.I see the fact that it can not be transitive on $M\times M$, I made it too simple. But when you say it maximizes the rank, what do you mean? This is my question

Comment: Looks like your second guess is right based on the proof in the paper. Also you didn't fully fix your link (the text of the link is the correct url, but not the actual hyperlink!).

Comment: Ok thanks, and sorry for the problems with the link which now should be finally fixed.